# Use JpaRepository with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to run my new spring boot project but I'm facing the following problems knowing that I followed the tutoriel with no mistakes.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mtaha.GlobalProject.Repositories.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.mtaha.GlobalProject.GlobalProjectApplication.main(GlobalProjectApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]

2019-11-14 10:24:34.627 ERROR 5340 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.mtaha.GlobalProject.Controllers.UserController required a bean of type 'com.mtaha.GlobalProject.Repositories.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mtaha.GlobalProject.Repositories.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

And when I solved this problem by adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` I get this error

```
Description:

Field userRepository in com.mtaha.GlobalProject.Controllers.UserController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

This is my code :

User.java

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, Date birthDate, String userName, String password) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

UserController.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mtaha.GlobalProject.Repositories.UserRepository;
import com.mtaha.GlobalProject.models.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public User getUser(@PathVariable long id) {
        return null;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public List<User> getAllUser() {

        return null;
    }

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mtaha.GlobalProject.models.User;


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

And RepositoryConfiguration.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.mtaha.GlobalProject.models"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RepositoryConfiguration {



}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Global
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Structure:

```
src/main/java
      |_com.mtaha.GlobalProject
         |__GlobalProjectApplication.java
         |__ServletInitialiser.java
      |_com.mtaha.GlobalProject.Controllers
         |__UserController.java
      |_com.mtaha.GlobalProject.models
         |__User.java
      |_com.mtaha.GlobalProject.Repositories
         |__UserRepository.java
         |__RepositoryConfiguration.java
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: Add `@Repository` on `public interface UserRepository extends xxxxx`

Comment: Remove repository configuration and paste stack trace, not cause

Comment: share the package structure

Comment: @JonathanJohx the problem persist

Comment: @emotionlessbananas i get the first error

Comment: By stacktrace i meant starting from 'caused by'. Side note: in stack trace check/post the reason for problem by reading from bottom to top. And are you following exact structure recommend by spring. And try creating new project from `spring.io`

Comment: try adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on main class

Comment: @emotionlessbananas when I run as spring boot application this is all what I get in the console

Comment: @Deadpool I'm already using ```@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})``` on main class

Comment: do you have anything in this class `RepositoryConfiguration` ? why do you need this @tahamanar ?

Comment: Are you using embbeded tomcat? Is your SQL server configuration valid? Add `debug:true' then do clean installation. Then run. You will get more information.

Comment: @Deadpool No, I have only annotations

Comment: @emotionlessbananas yes, I'm using the embbeded tomcat. And by clean installation do you mean `mvn clean install` ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@EntityScan` annotation. Your repository package is not scanned.

Move your `RepositoryConfiguration.java` into the `com.mtaha.GlobalProject` package.

Or simply move all the other class level annotation from that class to the `GlobalProjectApplication.java`.

Comment: I moved these annotations to `GlobalProjectApplication.java`, nothing happens

Comment: did you also remove the `@EntityScan` ?